# Postgresql trigger function occasionally fails to update its target correctly – possible race condition?

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have a system that's set up as a series of `jobs` and `tasks`. Each job is made up of several tasks, and there's another `task_progress` table that does nothing but record the current state of each task. (This information is kept separate from the main `tasks` table for business reasons that are not relevant to this issue.)

The `jobs` table has an overall `status` column, which needs to get updated to `completed` when all of the job's tasks reach a terminal state (`ok` or `error`). This is handled by a trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_job_status_when_progress_changes()
  RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  current_job_id jobs.id%TYPE;
  pending integer;
BEGIN
  SELECT tasks.job_id INTO current_job_id
  FROM tasks WHERE tasks.id = NEW.task_id;

  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO pending
  FROM task_progress
  JOIN tasks ON task_progress.task_id = tasks.id
  WHERE tasks.job_id = current_job_id
  AND task_progress.status NOT IN ('ok', 'error');

  IF pending = 0 THEN
    UPDATE jobs
    SET status = 'completed', updated_at = NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'utc'
    WHERE jobs.id = current_job_id;
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql

CREATE TRIGGER task_progress_update_job_status
  AFTER UPDATE OR DELETE
  ON task_progress
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_job_status_when_progress_changes()
```

It's been almost entirely fine. But sometimes – like, maybe once every few hundred jobs – a job will fail to flip over to `completed` status. The progress rows are all correct; the business logic that displays a % complete based on the contents of the `task_progress` table hits 100%, but the status of the job stays at `processing`. We've been unable to reproduce it reliably; it's just something that happens now and then. But it's frustrating, and I'd like to nail it down.

There are no transactions involved; each task progress is updated atomically by the process that completes the task.

Is it possible to hit a situation where, e.g., the last two tasks in a job complete almost simultaneously, causing the trigger for Task A to see that Task B is still pending, and vice versa? I thought `FOR EACH ROW` was supposed to prevent race conditions like this, but I can't explain what I'm seeing otherwise.

What's my best option here?

Comment: How is `task_progress.status` set? If it is done as part of the `UPDATE` why not just test for it and do the `UPDATE` on `jobs`?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver `task_progress.status` is set by the process running the task. It doesn't have any access to or knowledge of any other tasks but its own (or even the job it's part of), so it can't update the `jobs` table itself.

Comment: Another possibility.  Remove the status from jobs, then create a jobs view which derives the status from looking at the individual task statuses. Then each task only has to worry about is own status. The trigger just goes away, no more race condition.

Comment: Thanks, @Belayer – the reason we can't just use an aggregate view is that we have a different trigger that issues a [`NOTIFY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-notify.html) when `job.status` changes. So the whole messaging flow depends on the job status actually updating at the right time, not just being able to read the status on demand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a race condition. If the last two tasks complete at about the same time, the trigger functions can run concurrently. Since the trigger runs as part of the transaction, and the transactions are both not committed yet, none of the trigger functions can see the data modifications made by the other transaction. So each believes there is still a task open.

You could use an advisory lock to make sure that that cannot happen: right before the `SELECT count(*) ...`, add

```
SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock(42);
```

That makes sure that no session will execute the query while another session that has already executed the query is still not committed, because the lock is held until the end of the transaction.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I can use an advisory lock on `current_job_id` (cast as a bigint) to make sure the lock is keyed on the specific job, so it won't lock out progress updates from other jobs. Since the `jobs` table uses a UUID as a primary key, it won't block anything else.

Comment: Yes, but watch out that you don't have too many different advisory locks. They may exhaust the lock table. But you can always increase `max_locks_per_transaction`.